# Fullcalendar 4 rrule plugin var from source

Tags: javascript, php, fullcalendar, rrule, fullcalendar-4

According to

https://fullcalendar.io/docs/rrule-plugin

The rrule plugin should be in the events module

My events module is being loaded form a database source using

```
<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

 calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
 plugins: ['bootstrap','interaction', 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 
          'rrulePlugin' ],
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek'
  },
  Duration: '00:15:00',  
  nowIndicator: true,
  defaultDate: new Date(),
  editable: true,
  eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
  events: 
     {
         url: 'renderevent.php',
         method: 'POST',
         rrule: { }
     }

    });     

   calendar.render();
  });
</script>
```

I source the (id , title , start , end) from the following phpcode , but how do i also source the rrule parameters (freq,interval, dstart, until) from within the same module.

```
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultset) ) {

if (($row['eventtype'] ==1) && ($row['repeatevent']=="never" )){
    $json[] = array (    
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'title' => $row['title'],
     //   'eventtype'=> $row['eventtype'],
        'start'=> $row['startdatetimeother'],   
        'end'=> $row['enddatetimeother'],
        'color'=> "#ff9999",
        'freq' => $row['repeatevent'],
            );


}


    if (($row['eventtype'] ==1) && ($row['repeatevent']!="never" )){
    $json[] = array (    
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'title' => $row['title'],
     //   'eventtype'=> $row['eventtype'],
        'start'=> $row['startdatetimeother'],   
        'end'=> $row['enddatetimeother'],
        'color'=> "#ff9999",
        'freq' => $row['repeatevent'],
        'interval' => $repeatinterval,
        'dtstart' => $row['startdatetimeother'],
        'until' => $row['enddatetimeother']
            );


}
```

Comment: `$json[] = array (    
        'id' => $row['id'],
        'title' => $row['title'],
     //   'eventtype'=> $row['eventtype'],
        'start'=> $row['startdatetimeother'],   
        'end'=> $row['enddatetimeother'],
        'color'=> "#ff9999",
        'rrule' => array(
        'freq' => $row['repeatevent'],
        'interval' => $repeatinterval,
        'dtstart' => $row['startdatetimeother'],
        'until' => $row['enddatetimeother']
            ));` - something like that?

Comment: Thanks ADyson , had to change up the code a bit to get it working .     
  'rrule' => array('dtstart' => $row['startdatetimeother'], 'freq' => 
  $row['repeatevent'] ),
  'duration'=>$row['durationevent']

Comment: If you fixed it and found the final solution that's great - please add it as an Answer so others can benefit from it (and potentially upvote it!)

Answer (score 1):

```
'rrule' => array('dtstart' => $row['startdatetimeother'],
'freq' => $row['repeatevent'] )

, 'duration'=>$row['durationevent']
```

The duration of the event has to be placed outside of the rrule array